# Thread safety of List<T> with One Writer, No Enumerators

Tags: c#, list, thread-safety, concurrent-programming

While going through some **database** code looking for a bug unrelated to this question, I noticed that in some places `List<T>` was being used inappropriately.  Specifically:

1. There were many threads concurrently accessing the `List` as readers, but using **indexes** into the `list` instead of `enumerators`.
2. There was a single writer to the `list`.
3. There was zero **synchronization**, readers and writers were accessing the `list` at the same time, but because of code structure the **last** element would never be accessed until the method that executed the `Add()` returned.
4. No elements were ever removed from the `list`.

By the **C#** documentation, this should not be thread safe. 
Yet it has never failed. I am wondering, because of the specific implementation of the `List` (I am assuming internally it's an **array** that **re-allocs** when it runs out of space), it the 1-writer 0-enumerator n-reader add-only scenario **accidentally** thread safe, or is there some unlikely scenario where this could blow up in the current **.NET4** implementation?

edit: Important detail I left out reading some of the replies.  The readers treat the `List` and its contents as read-only.

Answer (score 2):

This can and will blow.  It just hasn't yet.  Stale indices is usually the first thing that goes.  It will blow just when you don't want it to.  You are probably lucky at the moment.

As you are using .Net 4.0, I'd suggest changing the list to a suitable collection from System.Collections.Concurrent which is guaranteed to be thread safe.  I'd also avoid using array indices and switch to ConcurrentDictionary if you need to look up something:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287108.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Because of it has never failed or your application doesn't crash that doesn't mean that this scenario is thread safe. for instance suppose the writer thread does update a field within the list, lets say that is was a `long` field, at the same time the reader thread reading that field. the value returned maybe a bitwise combination of the two fields the old one and the new one! that could happen because the reader thread start reading the value from memory but before it finishes reading it the writer thread just updated it.

**Edit:** That of course if we suppose that the reader threads will just read all the data without updating anything, I am sure that they doesn't change the values of the arrays them self but, but they could change a property or field within the value they read. for instance:

```
for (int index =0 ; index < list.Count; index++)
{
    MyClass myClass = list[index];//ok we are just reading the value from list
    myClass.SomeInteger++;//boom the same variable will be updated from another threads...
}
```

This example not talking about thread safe of the list itself rather than the shared variables that the list exposed.

The conclusion is that you have to use a synchronization mechanism such as `lock` before interaction with the list, even if it has only one writer and no item removed, that will help you prevent tinny bugs and failure scenarios you are dispensable for in the first place.

Comment: Thread safety of the list does not have *anything* to do with thread-safety of the fields of the object which is in the list. Even if you make the actual list thread-safe the problem you are describing would still exist.

Comment: @Brois yes you are right, he should lock for every thing that can be updated from multithread.

Answer (score 0):

It follows then, that if the architecture is 32 bits, writing a field bigger than 32 bits, such as long and double, is not a thread safe operation; see the documentation for [System.Double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx?):

> Assigning an instance of this type is not thread safe on all hardware platforms because the 
>   binary representation of that instance might be too large to assign in a single atomic 
>   operation.

If the list is fixed in size, however, this situation matters only if the List is storing value types greater than 32 bits.  If the list is only holding reference types, then any thread safety issues stem from the reference types themselves, not from their storage and retrieval from the List. For instance, immutable reference types are less likely to cause thread safety issues than mutable reference types.

Moreover, you can't control the implementation details of List: that class was mainly designed for performance, and it's likely to change in the future with that aspect, rather than thread safety, in mind.

In particular, adding elements to a list or otherwise changing its size is not thread safe even if the list's elements are 32 bits long, since there is more involved in inserting, adding, or removing than just placing the element in the list.  If such operations are needed after other threads have access to the list, then locking access to the list or using a concurrent list implementation is a better choice.

Comment: The list isn't thread safe for 32 bit types on a 32 bit system either because adding an item to the list writes more than one value.  At a minimum it must write the new item and update the list size - once you are doing more than one operation without a lock there is no thread safety.  Not to mention what would happen when the list re-sizes itself.

Answer (score 0):

Thread safety only matters when data is modified more than once at a time. The number of readers does not matter. Even when someone is writing while someone reads, the reader either gets the old data or the new, it still works. The fact that elements can only be accessed after the Add() returns, prevents parts of the element being read seperately. If you would start using the Insert() method readers could get the wrong data.

Comment: I agree, especially after the OP's edit regarding read-only access of the readers.

Comment: -1. This is just wrong: *"Even when someone is writing while someone reads, the reader either gets the old data or the new, it still works."* Whether it works or not is an implementation detail of that particular data structure, and unless it's guaranteed then you can't rely on it. The [`List<T>` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) states that it can support multiple-readers-no-writers in a threadsafe way. The OP may have been lucky so far with multiple-readers-single-writer but there's no guarantee whatsoever that this will continue to be the case.

Comment: I think that issue is adressed because the only write he uses is Add and the new element only becomes accessible after the add returns. Remember, he's using some custom list implementation, not the List<T> version from the .NET framework.

Comment: @MrFox: It would be possible and not even terribly difficult for `List<T>` to be implemented in such a fashion that even without using any locks one could safely read or enumerate the list while a single thread was performing `Add` operations or indexed writes (but not `Insert`, `Remove`, or anything like that).  Nothing in the spec says that it is actually implemented in such fashion, however; at least with regard to enumeration, it clearly is not.

Answer (score 0):

First off, to some of the posts and comments, since when was documentation reliable?

Second, this answer is more to the general question than the specifics of the OP.

I agree with MrFox in theory because this all boils down to two questions:

1. Is the List class is implemented as a flat array?

If yes, then:

1. Can a write instruction be preempted in the middle of a write>

I believe this is not the case -- the full write will happen before anything can read that DWORD or whatever.  In other words, it will never happen that I write two of the four bytes of a DWORD and then you read 1/2 of the new value and 1/2 of the old one.

So, if you're indexing an array by providing an offset to some pointer, you can read safely without thread-locking.  If the List is doing more than just simple pointer math, then it is not thread safe.

If the List was not using a flat array, I think you would have seen it crash by now.

My own experience is that it is safe to read a single item from a List via index without thread-locking.  This is all just IMHO though, so take it for what it's worth.

Worst case, such as if you need to iterate through the list, the best thing to do is:

1. lock the List
2. create an array the same size
3. use CopyTo() to copy the List to the array
4. unlock the List
5. then iterate through the array instead of the list.

in (whatever you call the .net) C++:

```
  List<Object^>^ objects = gcnew List<Object^>^();
  // in some reader thread:
  Monitor::Enter(objects);
  array<Object^>^ objs = gcnew array<Object^>(objects->Count);
  objects->CopyTo(objs);
  Monitor::Exit(objects);
  // use objs array
```

Even with the memory allocation, this will be faster than locking the List and iterating through the entire thing before unlocking it.

Just a heads up though: if you want a fast system, thread-locking is your worst enemy.  Use [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) instead.  I can speak from experience, message-based synch is the right way to go.